# SQL n:m Inheritance join

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance, join, nm

I want to join a table which contains n:m relationship between groups. (Groups are defined in a separate table).
This table only has entries listing a member_group_id and a parent_group_id.

Given this structure:

```
id(int) | member_group_id(int) | parent_group_id(int)
```

The "base" query looks like this:

```
select p1.group_id, p2.group_id, p1.member_group_id, p2.member_group_id
from group_member_group as p1 
join group_member_group as p2 
on p2.member_group_id = p1.member_group_id
```

The "base" query correctly shows all relationships (I checked by doing it manually.)

The problem is when I try to apply a where clause to this query to filter for a specific group as "point of origin" (the first group for which I want all parent groups) it returns only the closest parents. For example like this:

```
select p1.group_id, p2.group_id, p1.member_group_id, p2.member_group_id
from group_member_group as p1 
join group_member_group as p2 
on p2.member_group_id = p1.member_group_id
where p1.group_id = 1
```

Can anyone give a clue how I can fix this? Or a different approach to realize this. (I suppose I could always do this in my C++ source code on the server side but I would have to transfer a entire table which has a high growth potential to the application server.)

UPDATE:

```
select p1.group_id, p2.group_id, p1.member_group_id, p2.member_group_id
from group_member_group as p1 
join group_member_group as p2 
on p2.group_id = p1.member_group_id
```

Typing mistake confirmed. Now I don't get past first level of inheritance period. Thanks at denied for pointing that out.

UPDATE2: Expected Result

```
id | group_id | member_group_id
--------------------------------
1  |    1     |    2
2  |    2     |    3
3  |    3     |    4
4  |    4     |    5
5  |    5     |    6
6  |    6     |    7
```

expected result:

### ids

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Please, give some examples in a tabular format

Comment: See update2 above for expected result. Basically I want all tables that a given table (in the example 1) inherits from directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
on p2.member_group_id = p1.member_group_id
```

it looks like mistake.

Maybe you wanted to type

```
on p2.parent_group_id = p1.member_group_id
```

Maybe you should look for *Nested Set Model* for parent-child relationships.

It's much easier to make queries like this in that model.

Comment: That wouldn't work since a group can be in N other groups and these groups can in turn be in N groups and so on...

Comment: If you have many-to-many relationship (as i understand) - then you should use another table to store the relations. for an instance, table groups_relations(parent_id number, child_id number)

Comment: (The reason why I cant use Nested Parent Child relationships is that they resemble a tree like model. Which means a group in one branch can't be a member to a group in an other branch.)

Comment: That table I described above is exactly what you just described. The table that contains groups, their names etc is a separate one. The table above only exists to map many to many relationships (also known as n:m (n to m)).

Comment: Oh, i am sorry - your table is already created for store many-to-many relationships :)

Comment: For many-to-many structure approach like in your question is ok. And if group_id, member_group_id are indexed - your query will be fast. But level of depth in query result depends on number of self joins in query. i.e. if you want to unroll hierarchy down to fourth level (parent-childs-childs-childs) - you should use two self joins

Comment: If I understood that correctly it means that for a depth of N group0 is in group1 is in group2 is in.... is in groupN I would need N self joins? So if a group is 10 levels up I need to self join 10 times? This would mean that I cannot achieve my goal with SQL only.

Comment: Not exactly. In fact, each row in your table stores 2 levels (parent-child). So for a depth N you have to use N-2 self joins. I'm afraid that in MySQL you can't extract all levels in one query without knowing N. In ORACLE you can use CONNECT BY clause, but there is no one in MySQL.

Comment: I found something that might be helpful for you : http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/sp/#14

Comment: Thanks but I think String handling takes more performance then doing a few left joins with large intervals before data has to be reloaded (I intend to cache data for a given time based on last access and just run a "garbage collect" which eliminates old entries after a given time. As long as there is free memory that time can be very long (perhaps days or longer) and when using a non-object based approach the memory consumption should be linear and predictable.)

Answer (score 0):

I "developed" an other "solution" to this if you wanna call it that since it technically is not a single query anymore.

I wrote a MySQL procedure which does exactly what I want. It searches for all parents to a single node, then for the parents of the next level and so on and checks if new results are found (need to detect loops in case they happen, which should be prevented by application logic but to be on the save side I also restricted the max distance to a given amount).

But it really is a pain in the ass and has to be modified for every table it needs to be used on.

I guess I will stick with a tree model and just put "accounts" if you wanna call them that in multiple groups. Meaning a account has a 1:n relationship with groups and a group has a n:1 relationship to parents (n groups have 1 parent, that parent may have an other parent up until the "root" node (classic tree)).